# Replace all values in one row to N/A

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I'm trying to figure out how to change all of the values in one row to N/A. For example. I need to replace rows 77 132 140 142 155 156 157 and 175 with N/A across all columns. For example:

```
RS,RPHG,LPHG,RITC
13.7801604545457,3.10785528409178,-38.443658181819,-8.25890473295385
-12.5663095454547,-33.8395547159089,-3.44606818181819,-24.8157817329538
35.1140204545463,-35.4853647159089,-33.8231881818192,26.6855902670459
-29.9357495454533,-34.5783047159075,-50.3323381818191,2.0808182670462
```

Comment: This question lacks an expected result given (what I presume is) the given input.

Comment: the actual file has more rows, I'm just not able to add them because of a character limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, -vOFS=, 'FNR==2 || FNR==4 { for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i="N/A" } 1' file
RS,RPHG,LPHG,RITC
N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
-12.5663095454547,-33.8395547159089,-3.44606818181819,-24.8157817329538
N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
-29.9357495454533,-34.5783047159075,-50.3323381818191,2.0808182670462
```

`FNR` is the ordinal number of the current record in the current file ("the line number in the current file"). If it's two or four, we loop over all fields (from 1 to `NF`, the number of fields) and set each field to the string `N/A`.  The trailing `1` at the end is a short way of writing `{ print }` and will cause all lines (modified or not) to be printed.

If you have an additional file with all the line number that should be removed (one number per line):

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next }
                 FNR in a { for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i="N/A" } 1' lines file
```

Where `lines` is the file with line numbers.

Here, if `FNR==NR` then we're reading from the *first* file (the `lines` file).  In that case, we create an entry in the array `a` with the line number as the key, and the continue with the next line. `NR` is the *total* number of lines read so far, and it will be equal to `FNR` until we start reading from the second file.

If `FNR` is not equal to `NR`, then we're reading the *second* file (the `file` file, containing the data). We then test if the current line number is a key in the array `a`, and if it is, we replace all fields as before with `N/A`.

Comment: Thank you! That second set of code is particularly helpful for my dataset.

Comment: ..and when you say "one number per line" do you mean one number per row?

Comment: @Rachel Yes, exactly. The `lines` file should just be a set of line numbers, one number per row/line.

Comment: To make the FNR checking a little easier/shorter, `awk -F, -vOFS=, 'FNR ~ /^(77|132|140|142|155|156|157|175)$/{for(i=0;++i<=NF;)$i="N/A"}1' file`

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda when I try to run this, I'm getting the following error:

awk: cmd. line:1: FNR==NR { a[]; next }
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: error: invalid subscript expression

Essentially, it seems to be missing whatever $1 is. Do you have other suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: @Rachel Make sure that the `awk` script is within single quotes, not double quotes.  With double quotes, the shell would try to interpret things like `$1` as a shell variable, which it's not.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not working with only single quotes

Comment: @Rachel I've tested the code in my answer an extra time now and it works. What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

One way, with `sed`:

```
sed '
77c\
N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
132c\
N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
140c\
N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
142c\
N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
155c\
N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
156c\
N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
157c\
N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
175c\
N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
' input.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -vOFS=, '{
  if (NR==77 || NR=132 || NR==140 || NR==142 || NR==155 || NR==156 || NR==157 || NR==175)
    $1=$2=$3=$4="N/A"
    print
}' input.csv
```

To create a new file with the output just use the shell `>` redirect operator:

```
awk -vOFS=, '{
      if (NR==77 || NR=132 || NR==140 || NR==142 || NR==155 || NR==156 || NR==157 || NR==175)
        $1=$2=$3=$4="N/A"
        print
    }' input.csv > newfile.csv
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to create a new file with these changes, leaving the original file unchanged?

Answer (score 1):

With to demonstrate with `awk` filtering on two lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="," } { if( NR == 77 || NR == 132 ) {for( i=1; i<=NF; i++) {$NF="N/A"} }; print }' input
```

Simply add more options to the `if` statement for all the lines in question.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` does that:

```
sed '77s/.*/N\/A,N\/A,N\/A,N\/A/;137s/.*/N\/A,N\/A,N\/A,N\/A/;...' YourFile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -F, -pale '
   $_ = join ",", qw[N/A] x @F
      if grep /^$.$/, qw/77 132 140 142 155 156 157  175/;
' input.csv
```

Or with `GNU sed` we could do using a mix of shell variables:

```
# give the rows to be made N/A in a comma separated fashion
rows2na='77,132,140,142,155,156,157,175'
b2sub=$(echo "$rows2na," | sed -e 's/,/ba\n/g')
sed -e "
    $b2sub
    b
    :a;s|[^,]*|N/A|g
" input.csv
```

Note:

1. Ensure that the input csv file really is comma separated and not any other character, say a TAB.
2. Ensure that the input file has unix line endings (the linefeed aka, newline "\n") and not windows or mac.

Comment: This might be more straightforward: `if grep {$. == $_} (77 132 140 142 155 156 157 175)`

Comment: That is probably correct. BTW the numbers need to be separated by commas. Here qw/.../  is better suited.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with sed

```
sed -E '
# for each needed rows jump to A
  77bA
  132bA
  140bA
  142bA
  155bA
  156bA
  157bA
  175bA
  b
  :A
# if the line is empty do nothing
    /^$/b
# Add comma at end of line
    s/$/,/
# Remove each not comma
    s/[^,]//g
# Substitute each comma by N/A,
    s/,/N\/A,/g
# Remove the last comma
    s/,$//
' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

bash: this will be slow

```
n=0
IFS=,
while read -ra fields; do
    case $((++n)) in
        77|132|140|142|155|156|157|175)
            for ((i=0; i<${#fields[@]}; i++)); do fields[i]="N/A"; done
            ;;
    esac
    echo "${fields[*]}"
done < file
```